# How can I deserialize a json string in to a model?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

***Hello Everyone***,

*A json model like the one below makes me return via an api.*

```
 {
  "data": [
    {
      "countryStats": {
        "order": 2,
        "confirmedCount": 15679,
        "deathCount": 277,
        "recovryCount": 333,
        "name": "Türkiye"
      },
      "cityStats": [

      ]
    },
    {
      "countryStats": {
        "order": 1,
        "confirmedCount": 216722,
        "deathCount": 5138,
        "recovryCount": 8672,
        "name": "Amerika Birleşik Devletleri"
      },
      "cityStats": [
        {
          "order": 1,
          "confirmedCount": 84070,
          "deathCount": 1941,
          "recovryCount": 0,
          "name": "New York"
        },..
```

*I am pulling this json data with the code below.*

```
static string GET(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            try
            {
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                WebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response;
                using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
                    String errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    // log errorText
                }
                throw;
            }
        }
```

***Here comes a string expression for me. I want to assign this string expression to my model, how do I do that.***

**My model**

```
public class CountryStats
    {
        public int Order  { get; set; }
        public int ConfirmedCount { get; set; }
        public int DeathCount { get; set; }
        public int RecovryCount { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<CountryStats> CityStats { get; set; }
    }
```

*I'm trying to translate it like this*

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CountryStats>>(res);
```

**But I get an error**

[image]

Comment: _Edit-Paste Special-Paste JSON as classes_ will give you a correct object model

Comment: Your sample JSON isnt a `List<CountryStats>`... Its an _object_ with a single property ("data")

Comment: There are repetitive statements, but how should I write it there

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski 
I did not understand much from your answer

Comment: @MuhammetCaylak there are hundreds of duplicates, how to properly map json to object model. The command above allows you to do that in visual studio. Sites like http://json2csharp.com/ can also do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change the model to this

```cs
public class BaseClass
{
    public List<CountryStats> Data { get; set; }
}
public class CountryStats
{
    public int Order  { get; set; }
    public int ConfirmedCount { get; set; }
    public int DeathCount { get; set; }
    public int RecovryCount { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<CountryStats> CityStats { get; set; }
}
```

then deserialize response to `BaseClass`

```cs
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaseClass>(res);
```

**Update**

try this to deserialize Turkish word

```cs
res = res.Replace("\"","'");
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaseClass>(res);
```

or

```cs
var result = HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaseClass>(res));
```

Comment: Thank u , @patrick-mcvay As you said, thank you very much for the information that you gave. Worked for me

Comment: @MuhammetCaylak Glad I could help :)

Comment: other questions is , 
I am having a problem because the data contains Turkish characters , for example ( " Türkiye "  / " T\\u00FCrkiye" )

Comment: @MuhammetCaylak i updated my answer and hope help you

Comment: My problem is , There is a problem with the incoming data . Problem is res

Comment: [link](https://ibb.co/XyvYCfF)   The api url I use : [link](https://corona.cbddo.gov.tr/Home/GetTotalData2?_=1585321922837)  
I'm using a url like this. However citystats data is not being set , 
I returned in a string of "Turkey", "United States" are phrases such. These statements are not coming properly.  @Farhad Zamani 
I need your help

Comment: @MuhammetCaylak it's not a bug, it's a feature :-D

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your model. It should look like below.

```
public class CountryStatsCollection
{
    public List<ContryStats> Data { get; set }
}

public class CountryStats
    {
        public int Order  { get; set; }
        public int ConfirmedCount { get; set; }
        public int DeathCount { get; set; }
        public int RecovryCount { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<CountryStats> CityStats { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Woww, you're really great. Thanks to you, I learned a good thing thanks to you. It is less how much I really thank you. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In addtion to other answers, if you are not sure that some fields may be null or not, this would help:

```
public partial class Welcome
{
    [JsonProperty("data", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public List<Datum> Data { get; set; }
}

public partial class Datum
{
    [JsonProperty("countryStats", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public CountryStats CountryStats { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("cityStats", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public List<object> CityStats { get; set; }
}

public partial class CountryStats
{
    [JsonProperty("order", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public long? Order { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("confirmedCount", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public long? ConfirmedCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("deathCount", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public long? DeathCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("recovryCount", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public long? RecovryCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize it:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Welcome>(res);
```